# V8 isolates mapped memory leaks

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

V8 developer is needed.

I've noticed that the following code leaks mapped memory (mmap, munmap), concretely the amount of mapped regions within `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` continuously grows and hits the system limit pretty quickly (`/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count`).

```cplusplus
void f() {
  auto platform = v8::platform::CreateDefaultPlatform();
  v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;

  create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
    v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();

  v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform);
  v8::V8::Initialize();

  for (;;) {
    std::shared_ptr<v8::Isolate> isolate(v8::Isolate::New(create_params), [](v8::Isolate* i){ i->Dispose(); });
  }

  v8::V8::Dispose();
  v8::V8::ShutdownPlatform();

  delete platform;
  delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
}
```

I've played a little bit with `platform-linux.cc` file and have found that `UncommitRegion` call just remaps region with `PROT_NONE`, but not release it. Probably thats somehow related to that problem..

There are several reasons why we recreate isolates during the program execution.

The first one is that creating new isolate along with discarding the old one is more predictable in terms of GC. Basically, I found that doing

```cplusplus
auto remoteOldIsolate = std::async(
    std::launch::async,
    [](decltype(this->_isolate) isolateToRemove) { isolateToRemove->Dispose(); },
    this->_isolate
);

this->_isolate = v8::Isolate::New(cce::Isolate::_createParams);

//
```

is more predictable and faster than call to `LowMemoryNotification`. So we monitor memory consumptions using `GetHeapStatistics` and recreate isolate when it hits the limit. Turns out we cannot consider GC activity as a part of code execution, this leads to bad user experience.

The second reason is that having isolate per code allows as to run several codes in parallel, otherwise `v8::Locker` will block second code for that particular isolate.

---

Looks like at this stage I have no choices and will rewrite application to have a pool of isolates and persistent context per code..of course this way `code#1` may affect `code#2` by doing many allocations and GC will run on `code2` with no allocations at all, but at least it will not leak.

---

PS. I've mentioned that we use `GetHeapStatistics` for memory monitoring. I want to clarify a little bit that part.

In our case its a big problem when GC works during code execution. Each code has execution timeout (100-500ms). Having GC activity during code execution locks code and sometimes we have timeouts just for assignment operation. GC callbacks don't give you enough accuracy, so we cannot rely on them.

What we actually do, we specify `--max-old-space-size=32000` (32GB). That way GC don't want to run, cuz it should see that a lot of memory exists. And using `GetHeapStatistics` (along with isolate recreation I've mentioned above) we have manual memory monitoring.

---

PPS. I also mentioned that sharing isolate between codes may affect users.
Say you have `user#1` and `user#2`. Each of them have their own code, both are unrelated. `code#1` has a loop with tremendous memory allocation, `code#2` is just an assignment operation. Chances are GC will run during `code#2` and `user#2` will receive timeout.

Answer (score 0):

> V8 developer is needed.

Please file a bug at [crbug.com/v8/new](https://crbug.com/v8/new). Note that this issue will probably be considered low priority; we generally assume that the number of Isolates per process remains reasonably small (i.e., not thousands or millions).

> have a pool of isolates

Yes, that's probably the way to go. In particular, as you already wrote, you will need one Isolate per thread if you want to execute scripts in parallel.

> this way code#1 may affect code#2 by doing many allocations and GC will run on code2 with no allocations at all

No, that can't happen. Only allocations trigger GC activity. Allocation-free code will spend zero time doing GC. Also (as we discussed before in your earlier question), GC activity is split into many tiny (typically sub-millisecond) steps (which in turn are triggered by allocations), so in particular a short-running bit of code will not encounter some huge GC pause.

> sometimes we have timeouts just for assignment operation

That sounds surprising, and doesn't sound GC-related; I would bet that something else is going on, but I don't have a guess as to what that might be. Do you have a repro?

> we specify --max-old-space-size=32000 (32GB). That way GC don't want to run, cuz it should see that a lot of memory exists. And using GetHeapStatistics (along with isolate recreation I've mentioned above) we have manual memory monitoring.

Have you tried *not* doing any of that? V8's GC is very finely tuned by default, and I would assume that side-stepping it in this way is causing more problems than it solves. Of course you can experiment with whatever you like; but if the resulting behavior isn't what you were hoping for, then my first suggestion is to just let V8 do its thing, and only interfere if you find that the *default behavior* is somehow unsatisfactory.

> code#1 has a loop with tremendous memory allocation, code#2 is just an assignment operation. Chances are GC will run during code#2 and user#2 will receive timeout.

Again: no. Code that doesn't allocate will not be interrupted by GC. And several functions in the same Isolate can never run in parallel; only one thread may be active in one Isolate at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. By saying 'just an assignment operation' I mean some really small memory allocation, like single object creation, etc..I'm sorry for that confusion.

Comment: Created an issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=10093
Will it have some impact to reproduce same behavior on the last v8 version ?

Comment: And, probably you have an idea of what we can fix within v8 in order to deallocates mmaps. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding versions: yes, sure. Nobody cares about 5.6 any more. The first thing you should try is to update.